# Dynamically select a column in PySpark based on the value of another column

Tags: pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe that contains dynamic number of columns - auto_id, val0, name0, val1, name1,...., valxx, namexx (where xx is dynamic, but less than 100).

I want to append a new column to the dataframe based on the following logic - for every row, one of the "name_" columns contains the string "Standard". I want to find that column and get the value of the corresponding val column (with the same index) and put it into the new column.

E.g. For the first row, it could be the name15 column that contains "Standard", so I need the value of val15.
For the second row, it could be the name31 column that contains "Standard", so I need the value of val31, etc.

Probably, I could achieve this the below nasty statement, but it would only work if the number of columns were static

```
`df1 = df.withColumn("new_column", 
      when((col("name0") == "Standard"), col("val0"))
     .when((col("name1") == "Standard"), col("val1"))....`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could dynamically create a list of case statements for each column and pass it to a `coalesce`.

here's an example

```py
allcols = data_sdf.drop('auto_id').columns
namecols = sorted([k for k in allcols if k.startswith('name')])
valcols = sorted([k for k in allcols if k.startswith('val')])

# create list of case statements
case_statements = map(lambda x: func.when(func.col(x[0]) == 'standard', func.col(x[1])), list(zip(namecols, valcols)))

# [Column<'CASE WHEN (name0 = standard) THEN val0 END'>,
#  Column<'CASE WHEN (name1 = standard) THEN val1 END'>,
#  Column<'CASE WHEN (name2 = standard) THEN val2 END'>]

# pass case statements to a coalesce
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('new_col', func.coalesce(*case_statements)). \
    show()

# +-------+------------+----+------------+----+-----+----+-------+
# |auto_id|       name0|val0|       name1|val1|name2|val2|new_col|
# +-------+------------+----+------------+----+-----+----+-------+
# |      1|    standard| foo|non-standard| bar| blah|bleh|    foo|
# |      2|non-standard| foo|    standard| bar| blah|bleh|    bar|
# +-------+------------+----+------------+----+-----+----+-------+
```

---

you could also chain the case statements dynamically using a reduce

```py
case_statement = reduce(lambda x, y: x.when(func.col(y[0]) == 'standard', func.col(y[1])), zip(namecols, valcols), func)
# Column<'CASE WHEN (name0 = standard) THEN val0 WHEN (name1 = standard) THEN val1 WHEN (name2 = standard) THEN val2 END'>

# pass it within withColumn
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('new_col', case_statement). \
    show()

# +-------+------------+----+------------+----+-----+----+-------+
# |auto_id|       name0|val0|       name1|val1|name2|val2|new_col|
# +-------+------------+----+------------+----+-----+----+-------+
# |      1|    standard| foo|non-standard| bar| blah|bleh|    foo|
# |      2|non-standard| foo|    standard| bar| blah|bleh|    bar|
# +-------+------------+----+------------+----+-----+----+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you for providing these two approaches, very helpful. I modified the first one to make it more understandable for me as a newbie.


`case_statement = [when(col(name_col) == 'Standard', col(val_col)) for name_col, val_col in zip(namecols, valcols)]`

and then perform `coalesce`